# Is there a way to Fix a Google Maps Marker to the Center of its Map always?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mobile, google-maps-api-3

To be more precise, what I try to accomplish is that while I ***Drag*** a Google Map there's a Google Maps **Marker** *that stays fixed at the center of the map at all times*.
This will improve User experience in my opinion, This is how I'm doing it now:

```
var map, marker, options;

options = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
  zoom: 15,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  overviewMapControl: false,
  zoomControl: true,
  draggable: true
};

map = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer, options);

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
  map: map,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});

//This line is what makes the Marker stick to the center of the map
marker.bindTo('position', map, 'center');
```

The problem I have with the code above is that.. When I drag the map underneath the Marker **it's not smooth enough**, ie. the Marker makes a wierd *jump* from the 'last' center to the 'new' center when dragging ends. (this is more noticeable on mobile devices), Therefore what I need is that the Marker is **Really permanently fixed** to the Center of its Map.

Is there a way to get this done? (I think I've seen this in a web-site once)

Let me know If you guys can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: did you try binding a google.maps.Marker's position to the google.maps.Map object's center property?

Comment: Negative, sir, The only solution I could come up with after reading the Docs, is the one you see there. If you could teach me how to do what you described, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Actually, I think that's what I'm doing now? right?

Comment: Yes.  And [it works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_markerCentered.html).  Does it not work for you?

Comment: Ok, Could you please try it on a mobile phone and let me know If it doesn't make any weird 'Jumps' as you drag the map :) Because there's where the problem arises. On a Desktop/laptop there's no apparent problem. Thanks for your replies, sir!

Comment: Nope. Don't have a mobile phone with data.

Comment: Bummer! Are you sure there isn't another way to do this? Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: Have you seen [this post](http://blog.mridey.com/2009/09/in-my-previous-post-i-showed-how-to.html), found on [this post to the group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/nicQZ0XXg28)

Comment: isn't it the marker is jumping on the link given by @geocodezip

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A different approach, that did not use a real `google.maps.Marker`:

after the map has been initialized, inject a div into the map-container, give it a className(e.g. `centerMarker`), the further things will be done via CSS:

```
.centerMarker{
  position:absolute;
  /*url of the marker*/
  background:url(http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker.png) no-repeat;
  /*center the marker*/
  top:50%;left:50%;

  z-index:1;
  /*fix offset when needed*/
  margin-left:-10px;
  margin-top:-34px;
  /*size of the image*/
  height:34px;
  width:20px;

  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/jcHqt/

Comment: Looks solid. I'll give a try soon, Thank you, sir. It appears to be exactly what I need. standby.

Comment: Nice answer, but is this possible to get map auto load when we move the map and one more thing can we get the location after dragging the map to new position.

Comment: This won't help you to get the lat and lng.  use the above approach paired with map.addListener('center_changed',callback() {}); 
to get the coordinates as well.

Comment: Nice Answer this is exactly what i was looking for, but i want to replace the marker with my custom one how do do that cause when i attempt to replace it, it disappears please help

Comment: @Alfred Alfizo Mosima: Hard to help you without seeing your attempt. You probably must modify the CSS for width/height/top/left . Example using your avatar(328x328px) http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/0fmdasrg/

Answer (score 50):

Rather than injecting an HTML component as suggested in *@Dr.Molle's* answer, why don't you use a CSS only solution.

It is simpler, more efficient and doesn't require you to even touch the DOM *(so there won't be any problems if Google changes their implementation)*.

Also since Google Maps doesn't apply any styles on the container element *(`#map`)* the solution is pretty safe.

```
#map {
    position: relative;
}

#map:after {
    width: 22px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin: -40px 0 0 -11px;
    background: url('https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/spotlight-poi_hdpi.png');
    background-size: 22px 40px; /* Since I used the HiDPI marker version this compensates for the 2x size */
    pointer-events: none; /* This disables clicks on the marker. Not fully supported by all major browsers, though */
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5047gmtt/4/).

Comment: Smart pure CSS approach! Never thought about using css peudo elements this way. Thanks.

Comment: Much better approach. I cringed at the injection method, especially because it used JQuery. Glad I scrolled down and found your answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can listen to the center changes via something like below, you will just have to update your view:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dragend", function() {
   console.log(map.getCenter().toUrlValue());
});
```

Current main used solution is for bringing up the InfoWindow only when onclick, I needed it on all the time like it is on Uber, so I replaced even the InfoWindow to a css only solution, updating the view the normal angular route with Ionic

HTML:

```
 <ion-content >
   <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true">
  </div>
  <div id="centerInfoBubble">
    <span>{{locationCtrl.coordinates}}</span>
  </div>
  <div id="centerMarker"></div>
 </div>
 </ion-content>
```

CSS:

```
#map {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
#centerInfoBubble {
  position: absolute;
  /*center the marker*/
 top: 38%;
 left: 22.5%;
 z-index: 1;
 width: 50%;
 height: 6%;
 border-radius: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #111;
 background-color: #444444;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 0.5% 5%;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#centerMarker {
 position: absolute;
 /*url of the marker*/
 background: url(http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker.png) no-repeat;
 /*center the marker*/
 top: 45%;
 left: 45%;
 z-index: 1;
 height: 10%;
 width: 10%;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Controller:

```
myModule.controller('LocationCtrl',['$scope','$cordovaGeolocation',function($scope,$cordovaGeolocation){
$scope.locationCtrl = {
    coordinates : null
};
var options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
var marker;

$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){

    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    var mapOptions = {
            center : latLng,
            zoom : 16,
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl : false,
            streetViewControl : false,
            zoomControl : false
    };

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    $scope.locationCtrl.coordinates = $scope.map.getCenter().toUrlValue();

    google.maps.event.addListener($scope.map, "dragend", function() {
        $scope.locationCtrl.coordinates = $scope.map.getCenter().toUrlValue();
        $scope.$apply();
    });

}, function(error){
console.log("Could not get location");
});

}]);
```

I don't know if there are performance issues with this yet, but looks quite smooth on the device, hope it helps someone

Comment: And I would put all that controller junk in a service or factory depending on your angular approach, i put it in a service, wrapped it in an init function, then call the service's init function from the controller using  $timeout for controller init

Answer (score 6):

If this can help, what I did is :

```
const myLatLng = {lat: 42, lng: 42};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: myLatLng,
  zoom: 14,
});

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
});

map.addListener('center_changed', () => {
  marker.setPosition(map.getCenter())
})
```

Comment: This is a good solution because it the marker lets the wheel event to prppagate to the map however it has lag and the marker jumps and viberates on drag.

Answer (score 1):

here i have added geo location button map with fixed pin to accurate your location

try it :)

```js
 
function loadScript(src,callback)
{ 
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    if(callback)script.onload=callback;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    script.src = src;
}
  
  loadScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&callback=initialize');

function initialize() 
  {   
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          zoom: 13, 
        });
latitudeTxt=document.getElementById('latitude');
longitudeTxt=document.getElementById('longitude');
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          draggable: false,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: {lat: 59.327, lng: 18.067}
        });
        var position = marker.getPosition();
        if(typeof position !== 'undefined')
        {
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        }
    
       map.addListener('center_changed', () => {
          
           marker.setPosition(map.getCenter())
            //get current location when we move the map 
            var NewMapCenter = map.getCenter();
           var latitude = NewMapCenter.lat();
     var longitude = NewMapCenter.lng();
           latitudeTxt.innerHTML =latitude;
           longitudeTxt.innerHTML =longitude;
        })
        
        addYourLocationButton(map, marker);
  }

 function geolocate() 
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            map.setCenter(geolocation); 
            });
        }
    }
 
 function addYourLocationButton (map, marker) 
{
    var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');

    var firstChild = document.createElement('button');
    firstChild.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    firstChild.style.border = 'none';
    firstChild.style.outline = 'none';
    firstChild.style.width = '28px';
    firstChild.style.height = '28px';
    firstChild.style.borderRadius = '2px';
    firstChild.style.boxShadow = '0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
    firstChild.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    firstChild.style.marginRight = '10px';
    firstChild.style.padding = '0';
    firstChild.title = 'Your Location';
    controlDiv.appendChild(firstChild);

    var secondChild = document.createElement('div');
    secondChild.style.margin = '5px';
    secondChild.style.width = '18px';
    secondChild.style.height = '18px';
    secondChild.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://maps.gstatic.com/tactile/mylocation/mylocation-sprite-2x.png)';
    secondChild.style.backgroundSize = '180px 18px';
    secondChild.style.backgroundPosition = '0 0';
    secondChild.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    firstChild.appendChild(secondChild);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function () {
        secondChild.style['background-position'] = '0 0';
    });

    firstChild.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var imgX = 0,
            animationInterval = setInterval(function () {
                imgX = -imgX - 18 ;
                secondChild.style['background-position'] = imgX+'px 0';
            }, 500);

        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                map.setCenter(latlng);
                clearInterval(animationInterval);
                secondChild.style['background-position'] = '-144px 0';
            });
        } else {
            clearInterval(animationInterval);
            secondChild.style['background-position'] = '0 0';
        }
    });

    controlDiv.index = 1;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(controlDiv);
}
```

```css
body,html,#map_canvas{height:100%;margin:0;}
#map_canvas .centerMarker{
  position:absolute;
  /*url of the marker*/
  background:url(http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker.png) no-repeat;
  /*center the marker*/
  top:50%;left:50%;
  z-index:1;
  /*fix offset when needed*/
  margin-left:-10px;
  margin-top:-34px;
  /*size of the image*/
  height:34px;
  width:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:400px"></div>
<div id="latitude">latitude</div>
<br/>
<div id="longitude">longitude</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use google map drag event:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
    marker.setPosition(map.getCenter()); 
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it as smooth as possible, and you can also get latlng at the same time.

```
    var map;
    var marker;
    var myInterval = setInterval(move, 1000 / 60);


    function handleEvent(event) {
        var latlng = map.getCenter();
        document.getElementById('lat').value = latlng.lat();
        document.getElementById('lng').value = latlng.lng();
    }



    // Initialize and add the map
    function initMap() {
        var uluru = { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036 };
        map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 4, center: uluru });
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: uluru,
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
        map.addListener('center_changed', handleEvent);
        document.getElementById('lat').value = "-25.344";
        document.getElementById('lng').value = "131.036";
    }


    function move(){
        try {
          var latlngMAP = map.getCenter();
          var latlngMARKER = marker.getPosition();
          tempLAT = lerp (latlngMARKER.lat(), latlngMAP.lat(), 0.1);
          tempLNG = lerp (latlngMARKER.lng(), latlngMAP.lng(), 0.1);
         var latlng = { lat: tempLAT, lng: tempLNG };
          marker.setPosition(latlng);
        } catch{
        }
    }
    function lerp(start, end, amt) {
         return (1-amt)*start+amt*end
    }
```