# How do I keep a marker centered on a Google Maps V3 javascript API map in mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want a marker to stay at the center of a map regardless of how the user drags. I've made this work in a Desktop browser like Chrome by updating the marker when the map fires a `center_changed` event:
http://jsfiddle.net/hu9fj/

However, the marker does not stay centered while dragging occurs in Safari with iPhone 4 or 5. Try the Fiddle out on an iPhone or simulator to see what I mean. I've listened to a variety of events to no avail.

I've even tried manually updating the marker every millisecond:

```
setInterval(function() {
  marker.setPosition(map.getCenter());
}, 1);
```

which keeps the marker centered on a Desktop browser, but again fails in mobile Safari.

How do I keep the marker at the center of a Google Maps v3 API map while the center changes in a mobile browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to Fix a Google Maps Marker to the Center of its Map always?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327254/is-there-a-way-to-fix-a-google-maps-marker-to-the-center-of-its-map-always)

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll do that and just overlay an absolutely-positioned image of a marker on the map.

Comment: Im guessing this means you wont know the center of the map while dragging?