# Remove Fixed Marker From Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I remove fixed marker, which is added to the div element containing google maps. The below line of code adds it using the class 'centerMarker', `$('<div/>').addClass('centerMarker').appendTo(map.getDiv());`
but how do I remove it (ideally using Javascript) ?

Here is the [full JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/jcHqt/) which adds the fixed marker (from [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327254/is-there-a-way-to-fix-a-google-maps-marker-to-the-center-of-its-map-always)). Code from JS Fiddle example is also shown below.

HTML

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

CSS

```
body,html,#map_canvas{height:100%;margin:0;}
#map_canvas .centerMarker{
  position:absolute;
  /*url of the marker*/
  background:url(http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker.png) no-repeat;
  /*center the marker*/
  top:50%;left:50%;
  z-index:1;
  /*fix offset when needed*/
  margin-left:-10px;
  margin-top:-34px;
  /*size of the image*/
  height:34px;
  width:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Javascript

```
function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 14,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5498783, 13.425209099999961),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
        $('<div/>').addClass('centerMarker').appendTo(map.getDiv())
             //do something onclick
            .click(function(){
               var that=$(this);
               if(!that.data('win')){
                that.data('win',new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'this is the center'}));
                that.data('win').bindTo('position',map,'center');
               }
               that.data('win').open(map);
            });
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: `jQuery.remove` https://api.jquery.com/remove/ Just curious, but why would you want a marker that is fixed (so that it moves independent of the map)?

Comment: @user44776  did you find a solution, if not give me more information about what you wanna do, so i can update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove it using [GoogleMaps DOMEvents](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-domListener?hl=es), for example lets say we want to remove it on the click (seems the more appropriate, since atleast we want to show the marker on the mark, if not, just remove it from the js code).

**Using Google Maps API**

Bassed on your example, just add this code, into the `initialize` function

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'click', removeMarker());
```

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcHqt/96/)

If you want to alert the user why the marker is gone, use a function instead, like this.

```
function removeMarker(ele){
           ele.remove();
            alert('Ok the marker is GONE!')
        }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'click', removeMarker(this));
```

Here is the other [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcHqt/97/) with the function.

**Pure Javascript**

If you want to remove it outside the initialize function with pure Javascript code, use the [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method like @Adam point on the comment, something like this.

```
function removeMarker(elem){
  console.log('removed')
      elem = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
      elem.childNodes[0].remove()

}
setTimeout(function(){ removeMarker(this) }, 3000);
```

Here is the pure JS [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcHqt/98/)