# How to implement centered marker in Google Maps API v3 with Ionic & Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I have created a map in my Ionic project using Maps API v3 and ngCordova to get my current location and with the following code:

```
    var options = {timeout: 10000, enablehighAccuracy: false};
    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options)
        .then(function (position) {
            var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
            var myLong = position.coords.longitude;
            console.log(myLat, myLong);
            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: center,
                zoom: 16,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                streetViewControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                zoomControl: false
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

I would like to create a marker on this map that will stay centered as the map is panned (similar to Hailo, Uber and others) so that the user can define a specific location simply by moving the map. I cannot find anything in the Maps API docs for this or any tutorials/hints.

Can anyone suggest a simple way to do this?
Also, am I right in thinking that when the user moves the map, the new coordinates of the centre of the map (where the marker is located) can be retrieved?

Comment: You could take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327254/is-there-a-way-to-fix-a-google-maps-marker-to-the-center-of-its-map-always

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I need. Any idea how to inject the div using Angular? My map div looks like this: <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div> .. no Angular directives involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```js
Javascript
    var options = {
      timeout: 10000,
      enablehighAccuracy: false
    };
    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options)
      .then(function(position) {
          var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
          var myLong = position.coords.longitude;
          console.log(myLat, myLong);
          var center = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong);
          var mapOptions = {
            center: center,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            zoomControl: false
          };
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
          //This is where the marker is added, an empty div is created, then a class of 'centerMarker' is added. Clickevents are registered and bound to the map.    
          $('<div/>').addClass('centerMarker').appendTo(map.getDiv())
            //do something onclick
            .click(function() {
              var that = $(this);
              if (!that.data('win')) {
                that.data('win', new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content: 'this is the center'
                }));
                that.data('win').bindTo('position', map, 'center');
              }
              that.data('win').open(map);
            });
        }
      },
      function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

```css
CSS
.centerMarker {
  position: absolute;
  /*url of the marker*/
  background: url(http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker.png) no-repeat;
  /*center the marker*/
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  /*fix offset when needed*/
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -34px;
  /*size of the image*/
  height: 34px;
  width: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```