# get the location of the stationary marker when map changes

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I'm developing a mobile app in Ionic.My requirement is I had a stationary image on the map, I need the location under that image.. Below is the code I found for dragging a marker and getting a location.

```
var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
            map: map,
            title: "My Location",
            draggable:true
        });

google.maps.event.addListener(loc, 'dragend', function(evt){
          console.log('Current Latitude:',evt.latLng.lat(),'Current Longitude:',evt.latLng.lng());
          });
```

But I need a stationary Image and get the location when the map is dragged some thing like in the below image. There is a rounded circle, when i drag the Map , I can see the location under the Image..

Anyone please guide me to achieve that.

Thankyou

---

[image]

Comment: I got 50% of my solution from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327254/is-there-a-way-to-fix-a-google-maps-marker-to-the-center-of-its-map-always), but I'm unable to get the location when map moves..Please help me

Comment: Post the updated code i.e the one which is 50% fixed. And just so I am clear which location is it that you are unable to get the one at the center or when the map is dragged?

Comment: Hi KayAnn..Thank you for your response.. I actually got solved my problem today.